# "reason not to understand each other"

Tags: sentence-construction

> **Our parents are much older than us, but that’s not the reason not to understand each other**.

Does that sentence sound good?

[I know it also is possible also to say: "... but that’s no reason not to understand each other."]

However I don't see the end of the sentence "reason not to understand each other" in common usage. Do you use any alternative phrases?

Comment: It suggests to me that the speaker will go on to say that something else **is** the reason!

Comment: @Kate Bunting, Is it possible to express "Our parents are much older than us, but that doesn't matter" using my template?

Comment: I was always taught to say "older than we are", but I know that some posters on this forum would say that that was pedantic and old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our parents are much older than us, but that’s not the reason for not understanding each other.

is better.